# Chef and chocolatey

Tags: chef-infra, chocolatey

My question is about Chef and Chocolatey…

I can see the **cookbook** here: https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-cookbook

And I can see the **resource** here: https://docs.chef.io/resource_chocolatey_package.html

I just don’t understand the relation between the cookbook and the resource.. Are they both needed if I wanted to install and use Chocolatey on my nodes?
(I have the latest versions of everything, I have a new environment)

Can someone tell me what’s the most efficient way to:

1. Install Chocolatey
2. Push packages using choco

I tried installed Notepad++ with the chocolatey_package resource, but I get this error: No candidate version available for notepadplusplus (I get the error even after manually installing Choco on my node)

Used syntax in the recipe:

```
chocolatey_package [ ‘notepadplusplus’ ] do
action :install
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either. We usually put things in a cookbook to start with, and then if there is a lot of user demand and the code is stabilized, we'll move it into Chef core.

The likely issue is that should be `chocolatey_package 'notepadplusplus' do` without the array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I use the chocolatey_package resource (like in the example you provided above) .. will Chef install chocolatey on the node automatically (if not already installed), and then proceed to install notepadplusplus? Or do you I need to provide additional code to perform the initial chocolatey installation?

Comment: The resource will not install it in either case, you need to use a recipe for that, either your own or the community cookbook. Also please don't cross post to the mailing list until more time has passed to avoid duplicate answers.

Comment: Thanks Coder.. sorry for the cross post I needed an answer soon.. By the way.. how do I install choco without the cookbook? (since my chef client is on version 13.7)

Comment: Assuming you mean without the community cookbook, you would write your own just like anything else.

Comment: Yes community cookbook.. I'm starting to get my vocabulary right.. thanks for your help man!